# convert json object to tree json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Checkout my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/imVinayPandya/ur1aLgpL/), but first read this. actually i was trying to convert tab indent text to tree. i saw some of related problem here but i didn't fond any correct answer. after solving this issue i am gonna post whole solution of "converting tab indent text to tree". but for now i am stuck in this code.

this is just an example about what i want. the first json object that i have, i want to convert that simple json to tree structured json based on level value.

**for example:** first json object level is 0 than i want to convert as root, next json object level is 1 than i want to convert this json object as children of first json object, next if json object level is 2 than i want to convert this third json object as children of second json object. see below code may be you can understand.

i want final output like this:

```
parent1
  child1
    child2
parent2
  child1
    child2
      child3
    child4
  child5
```

i have json object like this:

```
    [
  {
    "lable": "parent1",
    "level": 0
  },
  {
    "lable": "child1",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "lable": "child2",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "lable": "parent2",
    "level": 0
  },
  {
    "lable": "child1",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "lable": "child2",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "lable": "child3",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "lable": "child4",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "lable": "child5",
    "level": 1
  }
]
```

i want to convert it like this (please correct if my below json is not valid):

```
    [
  {
    "text": "parent1",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "child1",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "child2",
            "children": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "parent2",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "child1",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "child2",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "child3",
                "children": [

                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "text": "child4",
            "children": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "child5",
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: child 4 is level 2 and child 5 is level 1

Comment: oh... that was my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works for sorted data only. It utilized [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for gathering all data and a `for loop` for getting the right level for pushing the data.

```js
var data = [{ "lable": "parent1", "level": 0 }, { "lable": "child1", "level": 1 }, { "lable": "child2", "level": 2 }, { "lable": "parent2", "level": 0 }, { "lable": "child1", "level": 1 }, { "lable": "child2", "level": 2 }, { "lable": "child3", "level": 3 }, { "lable": "child4", "level": 1 }, { "lable": "child5", "level": 2 }],
    tree = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var i, p = r;
        for (i = 1; i <= a.level; i++) {
            p = p[p.length - 1].children;
        }
        p.push({ text: a.lable, children: [] });
        return r;
    }, []);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Another solution without a `for loop` and a temporary variable for the reference of the level.

```js
var data = [{ "lable": "parent1", "level": 0 }, { "lable": "child1", "level": 1 }, { "lable": "child2", "level": 2 }, { "lable": "parent2", "level": 0 }, { "lable": "child1", "level": 1 }, { "lable": "child2", "level": 2 }, { "lable": "child3", "level": 3 }, { "lable": "child4", "level": 1 }, { "lable": "child5", "level": 2 }],
    tree = [],
    level = [tree];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var o = { text: a.lable, children: [] };
    level[a.level].push(o);
    level[a.level + 1] = o.children;
    level.length = a.level + 2;
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: i got answer than you for you supports.

Answer (score 1):

Nina's answer is good but using `reduce` in that case is unnecessary since there is nested `for` loop. I'd suggest a bit simpler implementation with no nested loops:

```
function convertToTree(items) {
    var tree = [], stack = [];
    items.forEach(function(item){
        var leaf = { text: item.lable, children: [] };
        if (stack.length <= item.level) stack.push(leaf);
        item.level ? stack[item.level - 1].children.push(leaf) : tree.push(leaf);
        stack[item.level] = leaf;
    });
    return tree;
}
```

Modified fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ur1aLgpL/3/).

Comment: Sorry @NinaScholz appreciate your answer, yesterday i have made hug mistake in output json. i have updated it please check it again.

Comment: i got answer than you for you supports.